# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' for webscraping project

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

I'm making a program that scrapes this website. The data is collected, its only the names of items, platform I can use them on, and their price. I've made a data structure for the each scraped bit of information. But I am prompted with a type error when creating my dictionary?

I'm using python 3.7.2. Operating on windows 10.

```
import requests
import bs4
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bsoup

url = "https://ebgames.com.au/search?q=Skyrim"
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = Bsoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
platforms = soup.select(".product-top-level-group")
price = soup.select(".price")
names = soup.select(".product-title")
stripped_names = [na.text.strip() for na in names]
stripped_prices = [pri.text.strip() for pri in price]
stripped_platforms = [plat.text.strip() for plat in  platforms]




Game = {
    (stripped_names): {
        "Price": (stripped_prices),
        "Platform": [stripped_platforms]


    }
}

for Gamename, Gameinfo in Game.items():
    print(Gamename)
    print("Platform:", Gameinfo['Platform'])
    print("Price:", Gameinfo['Price'])
    print("\n")
```

This is my error:

```
"Platform": [stripped_platforms]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where you got that `dict` initialization syntax from, but that's not how it's done in Python.

Here's a nice way of doing it with `zip`:

```
stripped_names = ['Skyrim', 'Minecraft']
stripped_prices = ['$59.99', '$19.99']
stripped_platforms = ['PC', 'XBox One']

Game = {
    name: {
        "Price": price,
        "Platform": platform,
    } for name, price, platform in zip(
        stripped_names,
        stripped_prices,
        stripped_platforms,
    )
}

for Gamename, Gameinfo in Game.items():
    print(Gamename)
    print("Platform:", Gameinfo['Platform'])
    print("Price:", Gameinfo['Price'])
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```
Skyrim
Platform: PC
Price: $59.99


Minecraft
Platform: XBox One
Price: $19.99
```

Comment: Thanks, Although it works and I'm happy. I don't quite understand how it works. Could you please describe exactly what its doing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to initialize a dict with a key that's non-hashable, here `stripped_names` (you can read [this](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/what-are-hashable-objects/) to learn more about hashable objects). You can turn it into a `tuple` to make it hashable, or chose another key.

Next time, don't forget to post the whole traceback of your error, it will help people help you faster and better.